# How to copy some elements of a list based in it's position?

Tags: python, list

I'm making a simple grocery buying program that uses 2 fixed lists and 2 that can have elements added by the user.

```
product_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'banana', 'coconut']
price_list = [ 5.32 , 6.45 , 2.37 , 5.32, 6.45 ]

bought_product_list = [ ]
bought_price_list = [ ]


while True:
    
    product_code = input('Enter the product code: ')
    
    if product_code not in product_list:
        print('Invalid product code! Try again!')

    if product_code in product_list:
            quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
            for q in range(quantity):
                bought_product_list.append(product_code)
```

I can add the product_code to the bought_price_list, but I need a way to import the correct price associated with the product_code from the other lists.

Let's say the user types **apple with the quantity 2 and watermelon with the quantity 3**, the output should be:

```
bought_product_list = [ 'apple', 'apple', 'watermelon' , 'watermelon' , 'watermelon' ]
bought_price_list = [ 5.32 , 5.32 , 2.37 , 2.37 , 2.37 ]
```

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: The way you are storing products and prices is a well-known anti-pattern: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/ . You should be using a map.

Comment: Why don't you use a `dict` to store both `product_list` and `price_list`?

Comment: is the insertion order of the bought products important?

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of your code:

```
bought_price_list.append(price_list[product_list.index(product_code)])
```

or the better way is to make an dict from them like this:

```
product_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'banana', 'coconut']
price_list = [ 5.32 , 6.45 , 2.37 , 5.32, 6.45 ]

product_dict = {i:j for i,j in zip(product_list, price_list)}
```

Then you have:

```
{'apple': 5.32,
 'orange': 6.45,
 'watermelon': 2.37,
 'banana': 5.32,
 'coconut': 6.45}
```

so change your code inside the while:

```
product_code = input('Enter the product code: ')

if product_code not in product_list:
    print('Invalid product code! Try again!')

if product_code in product_dict:
    quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
    for q in range(quantity):
        bought_product_list.append(product_code)
        bought_price_list.append(product_dict[product_code])
```

Also you can enhance `for q in range(quantity):` like this:

```
if product_code in product_dict:
   quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
   bought_product_list += [product_code] * quantity
   bought_price_list += product_dict[product_code] * quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you don't need second check. You already make check before it. So it would be better to skip current iteration.
Remove this line

```py
if product_code in product_list:  ## delete this line
```

and edit this one:

```py
if product_code not in product_list:
    print('Invalid product code! Try again!')
    continue
```

Then you need to find proper price for the product. This can be done using `index` method on the list.

and lastly you insert the data.
Finally code will look like this:

```py
product_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'banana', 'coconut']
price_list = [ 5.32 , 6.45 , 2.37 , 5.32, 6.45 ]

bought_product_list = [ ]
bought_price_list = [ ]


while True:
    
    product_code = input('Enter the product code: ')
    
    if product_code not in product_list:
        print('Invalid product code! Try again!')
        continue
    
    # get index of product code to extract product price
    product_code_idx = product_list.index(product_code)
    product_price = price_list[product_code_idx]

    quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))

    bought_product_list.extend([product_code] * quantity)
    bought_price_list.extend([product_price] * quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)
for this use case.
A solution for your problem would be to use a single dictionary with the product as key and price as value.
To strictly adhere to your output, without changing your conditions, you can do this:

```py
product_list = {'apple': 5.32, 'orange': 6.45, 'watermelon': 2.37, 'banana': 5.32, 'coconut': 6.45}
bought_product_list = []


while True:
    
    product_code = input('Enter the product code: ')
    
    if product_code not in product_list.keys():
        print('Invalid product code! Try again!')

    if product_code in product_list.keys():
            quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
            for q in range(quantity):
                bought_product_list.append(product_code)
                bought_price_list.append(product_list[product_code])
```

however I would advise to use `else` on the second condition.